# Double value adding is not proper

Tags: java, double

Here the problem is when I add amountbeforetax which is 68.0 with tax amount which is 14.96, it is giving me amountWithTax is equal to 82.96000000000001, but when i add with tax amount which is 14.97 or 14.95, 14.98 it is giving me proper value.

what is the problem here? why it is giving me such result?

```
      public class Calc {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        double discountAmount = 0;
        double amountBeforeTax = 0;
        double amountWithTax = 0;
        double taxAmount = 0;

        amountBeforeTax = 68.0;
        System.out.println("amountBeforeTax "+amountBeforeTax);
        taxAmount = 14.96;
        System.out.println("taxAmount "+taxAmount);
        amountBeforeTax-= discountAmount;
        System.out.println("amountBeforeTax after discount "+ amountBeforeTax);
        amountWithTax = amountBeforeTax + taxAmount;
        System.out.println("amountWithTax "+ amountWithTax);
    }
}
```

Comment: Time and time again people don't know how floating point arithmetic works in computers... Just search for this and you get a million answers

Comment: Please consider using BigDecimal for money type
for explanation of your issue see here:
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/